# What I can use in typescript instead wildcard

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface `ColumnDef`. I need to create 2 methods: `getValue` which will return type C, and `getComponent` which have input arg with type C. And it works well!

```
interface ColumnDef<R, C> {
  getValue: (rowData: R) => C;
  getComponent: (cellData: C) => ReactElement
}
```

Then I have created an array `ColumnDef`. I don't need to say second type for each column. (I want to use a generic type, like in java: `ColumnDef<R, ?>[]`) I only need types to match in `getValue` and `getComponent` for each column. I try to use "any" type, like this `ColumnDef<R, any>[];` but it brokes types matching, like this code:

```
interface ColumnDef<R> {
  getValue: (rowData: R) => any;
  getComponent: (cellData: any) => ReactElement
}
```

I would like to use it so:

```
const columns: ColumnDef<R, any>[] = [
    { getValue: (rowData: R) => rowData.name, getComponent: (name: string) => Label(name)},
    { getValue: (rowData: R) => rowData.size, getComponent: (size: number) => NumberBox(size)}  
  ]
```

Additional, minimal reproducible example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

interface TestData {
  name: string,
  size: number
}

interface ColumnDef<R, C> {
  getValue: (rowData: R) => C;
  getComponent: (cellData: C) => ReactElement
}
function NumberBox(size: number): ReactElement {
  return <div>{size}</div>
}

const columns: ColumnDef<TestData, any>[] = [
  { getValue: (rowData: TestData) => rowData.name, getComponent: (name: number) => NumberBox(name)},  // It is incorrect: name is not number!
  { getValue: (rowData: TestData) => rowData.size, getComponent: (size: number) => NumberBox(size)}  // It is correct: size is number!
]

console.log(columns)
```

Comment: `(C: cellData) =>` should be `(cellData: C) =>`, I guess?  Ideally example code should be tested in an IDE and constitute a [mcve] so others can help you more easily.

Comment: Okay, you've fixed the error there, but could you please work on a [mcve] that shows how you intend to create and use one of these arrays?  TypeScript lacks direct support for [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) (which is what wildcards in Java generics basically are) so you have to work around it somehow.  The use of `any` is often good enough for people who would rather have convenience over strict type safety.  There are safer options, but I'd like more info on the use case before I go too far in one direction with a solution.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! I added more info to question

Comment: What is `R` in `const columns: ColumnDef<R, any>[]`?  A [mcve] should be something I can drop into an IDE (preferably a standalone one like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and see what's going on.  If I do that right now I'm faced with the fact that `R` is not defined, and neither is `Label` or `NumberBox`.  I will probably answer this question regardless but it would be nice to have something I can actually *test*.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your patience. I added minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not have direct support for [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), which is what wildcards in Java generic essentially are.  An existential type is a different sort of generic type parameter from the one available in TypeScript.

In TypeScript, if you say `interface ColumnDef<R, C> {...}` you are saying that this definition works for *all* specifications of `R` and `C`.  To talk about an instance of `ColumnDef<R, C>` meaningfully, you need to specify both `R` and `C`.

But what you're looking for is a type like `interface ColumnDef<R, exists C> {...}` which works for *all* specifications of `R`, but for *some unknown* specification of `C`.  To talk about an instance of `ColumnDef<R, exists C>` meaninfully, you need to *specify* `R`, but all you need to know about `C` is that there is one.

Since TypeScript has no direct support for this, you have to do various workarounds.

---

To talk about this concretely I will make a few `ColumnDef<R, C>` objects and one which fails to be one:

```
const cd1: ColumnDef<number, string> = {
  getValue(r) { return r.toFixed(0) },
  getComponent(c) { c.toUpperCase(); return reactElement; }
}
const cd2: ColumnDef<number, boolean> = {
  getValue(r) { return r > 3 },
  getComponent(c) { (c === true); return reactElement; }
}
const cdBad = {
  getValue(r: number) { return r.toFixed(0) },
  getComponent(c: boolean) { (c === true); return reactElement; }
}
```

---

The simplest workaround is to use `any` in place of `exists C`.  This will allow just about anything you need to allow, but it will not prohibit some mistakes.  Something like `cdBad` will be accepted:

```
const columnDefArray: ColumnDef<number, any>[] = 
  [cd1, cd2, cdBad]; // oops, no error, but ‍♂️
```

As a workaround you could make sure that all your `ColumnDef<R, C>` instances are created via helper function or a class constructor:

```
class ColumnDefClass<R, C> {
  private onlyWayToMakeItIsWithTheCtor = true;
  constructor(
    public getValue: (rowData: R) => C,
    public getComponent: (cellData: C) => ReactElement) {
  }
}

const columnDefClassArray: ColumnDefClass<number, any>[] = [
  new ColumnDefClass(cd1.getValue, cd1.getComponent),
  new ColumnDefClass(cd2.getValue, cd2.getComponent),
  new ColumnDefClass(cdBad.getValue, cdBad.getComponent) // error!
]
```

Here because `ColumnDefClass` has a `private` property, you can't easily create instances of it without calling the constructor.  This will make it harder to violate your constraint.

Then, once you have an array of `ColumnDef<R, any>` you can map over it easily enough:

```
const numToElements = (n: number) => columnDefClassArray.map(
  <C>(cd: ColumnDef<number, C>) => cd.getComponent(cd.getValue(n))
);
// const numToElements: (n: number) => ReactElement[]
```

I recommend using a generic callback with `C` above to make that callback more type safe than `any` would give you.

---

If you want, you could actually encode existential types in TypeScript with curried generic functions (as shown [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#issuecomment-338045331)):

```
type SomeColumnDef<R> = <T>(cb: <C>(columnDef: ColumnDef<R, C>) => T) => T;
```

Here, `SomeColumnDef<R>` is a generic function which calls a callback on a `ColumnDef<R, C>` for some `C`.  Intuitively, since the caller of a generic function is the one that has to specify the generic parameter, by representing a value as a `Promise`-like thing that calls a callback that takes that value, you are changing who specifies the parameter.

You could convert a valid `ColumnDef<R, C>` to a `SomeColumnDef<R>` easily enough:

```
const toSomeColumnDef = <R, C>(columnDef: ColumnDef<R, C>): SomeColumnDef<R> =>
  cb => (cb(columnDef));
```

and get your array that way:

```
const columnDefArray = [toSomeColumnDef(cd1), toSomeColumnDef(cd2)];
// const columnDefArray: SomeColumnDef<number>[]
```

and also prohibit bad ones:

```
const badColumnDefArray = 
  [toSomeColumnDef(cd1), toSomeColumnDef(cd2), toSomeColumnDef(cdBad)] // error!
```

Then, `map`-ping over that array is a little more obscure, since you have to have an extra nested layer of callback, but it does work:

```
const numToElements = (n: number) => columnDefArray.map(someColumnDef => someColumnDef(
  <C>(cd: ColumnDef<number, C>) => cd.getComponent(cd.getValue(n))
));
// const numToElements: (n: number) => ReactElement[]
```

---

Finally, you could try to rely on TypeScript's type inference to treat `C` as an *array* of types itself, and for each index `I` in `C`, produce the corresponding array type with `ColumnDef<R, C[I]>` as its element.  This is enabled by [mapping over array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

But this starts getting closer to the limits of type inference in TypeScript.  Currying is weird but infers okay:

```
const curriedArray = <R>() => <C extends readonly any[]>(
  ...columnDefs: { [I in keyof C]: ColumnDef<R, C[I]> }
) => columnDefs;

const curriedColumnDefArray = curriedArray<number>()(cd1, cd2);
const badCurriedColumnDefArray = curriedArray<number>()(cd1, cd2, cdBad); // error!
```

Trying to use something more direct is incredibly ugly gets bogged down and I'm not going to explain it much:

```
type GetR<T extends ColumnDef<any, any>[]> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ColumnDef<infer R, any> ? R : never }[number];
type GetCs<T extends ColumnDef<any, any>[]> = Extract<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ColumnDef<any, infer C> ? C : never }, any[]>;
type _ValidateCDA<R, Cs extends any[]> = Extract<{ [K in keyof Cs]: ColumnDef<R, Cs[K]> }, ColumnDef<any, any>[]>;
type ValidateColumnDefArray<T extends ColumnDef<any, any>[]> = _ValidateCDA<GetR<T>, GetCs<T>>;

const asColumnDefArray = <T extends ValidateColumnDefArray<T>>(...arr: T) => arr;
const columnDefArray = asColumnDefArray(cd1, cd2);
const badColumnDefArray = asColumnDefArray(cd1, cd2, cdBad); // error!
```

Yuck.

But even if that works, iterating over the array is awful, because the `map()` callback over a tuple ends up requiring a big union of things. It's easier to just widen it to `ColumnDef<R, any>[]` first:

```
const numToElements = (n: number) => (columnDefArray as ColumnDef<number, any>[]).map(
  <C>(cd: ColumnDef<number, C>) => cd.getComponent(cd.getValue(n))
);
```

---

So there you go.  There are different ways to proceed and none of them are perfect.  Personally I'd probably stick with `any` because life is short.  But it's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQokscA3plTAKIA2WIWAO3gBfOERLlKeGLTp0ByfqjB4scAFK5k3AF6s6cOMCFYoBVXAAqWVDAAiyGMn2HDC-gC44tqMYDmADQGrqjAOlheAgCuIABGpsHCcobGMKbmuGoAwhDcMQJ2WAQAPBgBcFkAfC6uflgwAGraURFwABTEAO4OTl4YAJRwALzVWfSucHUwOeAQAoIwXm2Z3Nw9yF5ZgyPs0jx8C4nBBFEC+MBzcAByMfFQAEIQAB5toeGRt6b9fRz7-EI1QyUGBRKACODRVYAQnGcCSwVwc1scEReRAAlQm1y+UKJWstnW5WQAgAnpUANoAXWGcHJwUMbCmTTyrQ6EG6jg2Vhs9k522qXXWADp3FhylMZpB5kIlqKPnEvsNqjcFQ9nm1RYNhOU4AB6XVwACS8GA6GMiKglHwkUUalNEIg8Giqqh9NYk3qzJaS0FnK8+N5Tn5cF9TiFbzFHumJClCyWEfld2DKrujxeEa1hn1RpN6AtVsW3jCdvQzrursMlOSKKRuSwQu4ED8y2x6NQ-WrqXSFhyaIKRVK5SqgKjXtZoa5AyVFVhhglMbmcfaKzWfoqwewe14-xgRwRSPgUnwfyXm+P24WNMh3Bh1cRGPguAAJgBGLF93HFMumco+fzVIYRyZZosA6QY2GBUFwSgIUYAgAAxYAniwJ82gABi1IIJnnWZpRgZZwJRWCIAAVTAMBTCyNBQP6GgQ3qKD6K3A4hDopJDHYmsHxRJ8ACZ3xxAdvygcpYggOtiQAoDPRAsD3UgsEQzgaoAGY4Sw2p6klRchAI91lmGIZAJgKAWlo+iQUUo8uAvVi4T3Qx72RZ97mQJ8aRYN1gJZDpE0VCCGKs4jEOQ1CMPUrytIXPDli8MSJIEQiDKM4zTKwcyFOg35bJgNiHIhW1lAsABBUl9GrRyDxrD8imKy1kBJAT0U-YSiVJClqUA8lnxfcpn14vqn1cp9KTo7NxLAVBygECA4FMYgRLgWIongQA+DcAdl3AFgCQAhMkAeD+KpRbg0HQXtBIILIjtQVBBwqapPImQwwF8AA3Rw1DmbgSQAdQaywIAAWWQABrLBjUNVAvuAGAAAtLGhrAsjgqAaRMlpZ1cJzUfwaA2jdCYwCiWJuGAXBRxAn12XWPpgyyDSHrgAmiZJqNtLwpYVyp9dpzPGyWJgcC8fsiZ4QmTHqrOi7jrqqAGqa-tzsu67WpQdqqRpOl6fmToKlbeXJau5ZXyFbyWkGl9jai3CFn6OnXC1nWaoV47Dd4i3GhAwbXZw2MhBtwX7dO5qin11BDeGt2x0G8PvZ0-m9QNeboArVwqwOsXnT+k8hHQQCNT8qBg1RCXFelhqhRAZAwFx+niiqQ25Zaz5FqqQunzd1mFkNiPZMSjsJlot1s3TmJM5yzF2gEfON2yvmqWrEWCqUFRMjgTgzggJ8sE4J5TTSIRgG0cqJhgEkKLgABlEgEd1z8MCk4pLEqZZYi8Wun6LoOCAbgcylu4NLH-vQN0Ys4KX34IHeWNIbp1w-vLb+JRf4ty8GA6+jtSgAUqILXAsRpzPxbI7foA9gFVVgbiUuJJ1agKvhA3EhsXw2zgFQ8BN8igu36KNYh3FYhuRobVeqFCupMNQWdOhDChG8IIGw8o4iWGSJcm5dh8c5qWiToPA0YtSF8Jlo1C+1DZFfibh1OQnDkQZwgFnGAOcJ5T2nJogg5Dy6V1eHox205UAuJEYLN+9cHZnQMaqIclRW7t2ip3Z83cfK9zdIQ9GQ8qpmIsePPOEIm7T2YjuOe+VRRFRXoaAQBBTCCBXvdExj5QS+BQuQqBd82jBlrnNJ4e8nzoCkE+D6FDiQkipE-QWQo+l2PHmwckhojDghBiSCABAKiUngdA4ZlJqicUMIXWRqAgGixIeU4AKEJFVMArgLZlT+H+LuE-fodDPYDw2Vwnhhyny7P4TSA5lptlPnISc0wZyLk8QGjxYa5lsyJygK6A6J8z4AHF6gYAfg0ppJ19GdLamSbpHlaQAGlRlwHGZMqwMyrDkjRdSLAjTBDNN8Z-YoxgCnI1-p06oAB+TAcBIhYGeqYOE5JhIcOPqfNQkLpjXUsLC0l8K0GIpVsihZNJt4mWkMUIZGLjBYqwBMqZlg8WWAJUSklAgyUSOKOKql7LhyMqyMyiErL2Xagld09GYK1AAH1mTACfG9LIdhirQPQMSuFNqpWARlTLfA8r0WYuxVMrIqA8X6sQagLViyhwItJEijqlQ7W8rgM611aQHnaJhT6kV5L5YGuTRK1NNInXaBdW6j1xR+XQsfuUflkaH6VDTWnKqaBc0NSgUKgtur0BZrdbI95j8n59KFMgS0-pgxTqgOjDRI7HmAS7Uu7R3z+pXIxlVbh9y109pXagbtJIN18SjgosaCcVHAo7dxBJY8aTJOEsGfBZ0qloCLY3AJZaqT9EcVXLxMCnyzOVi3WxbcY4xXCSbUCUT+7rPsnIYQQA)